# Error in compilation of java code

Tags: java

```
shilps.java:198: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setDate(int,java.lang.String)
location: interface java.sql.PreparedStatement
                        ps.setDate(2, "2010-05-31");
                          ^
shilps.java:231: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setDate(int,java.lang.String)
location: interface java.sql.PreparedStatement
            ps.setDate(1, "2010-05-31");
              ^
shilps.java:232: setInt(int,int) in java.sql.PreparedStatement cannot be applied to
 (int,java.lang.String)
                        ps.setInt(2, "88349");
                          ^
shilps.java:293: e is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])
           }catch(Exception e){
                            ^
6 errors
```

Why the error is occurring?
 I have included:

```
 import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.sql.*;
```

Comment: Kind of hard to tell without the code. :)

Comment: where is the answer from baluc??

Comment: I cant see the answer from baluc..where it goes?

Comment: why he has removed his answer?

Answer (score 1):

1. the 2 param method in `PreparedStatement` for `setDate` takes a Calendar, not a String
2. the 2 param method in `PreparedStatement` for `setDate` takes a Calendar, not a String,
3. the 2 param method for `setInt` takes two `int`s, not and int and a String.
4. you already have another field in your `main` method called `e`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler tells you everything you needd to know:

```
setInt(int,int) in java.sql.PreparedStatement cannot be applied to (int,java.lang.String)
```

This means, you are passing a Value of Type `String` to a methods witch needs a `int`.
The API-Doc of PreparedStatement will show you, that there is a Method `setString(int,String)` which will take a String as second Parameter.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Maybe you wanted to call `ps.setInt(2, 88349);`

There ist a valiable called `e` already defined in that scope.

```
try{
    // some Code
    try{
        // some more coe
    } catch (Exception e){}
                      ^^^
              Compiling Error
} catch (Exception e){}
```